# Can I use image processing from an URL in Hugo?

Tags: go, hugo, static-site

The hugo [documentation](https://gohugo.io/content-management/image-processing) allows to use page and global resources to get an image. I was wondering if it's possible to get an image by an url? Something like this:

```golang
{{- $image := resources.Get "https://i.imgur.com/gZxmnyn.jpeg" -}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From hugo `v0.91.0`++ you can use `resources.GetRemote`

source : https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases/tag/v0.91.0

example:

```golang
{{ $image := resources.GetRemote "https://i.imgur.com/gZxmnyn.jpeg" }}
```